# I need to allocate a url to very student name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, url, constants

The name list is supposedly as below:

Rose : 35621548

Jack : 32658495

Lita : 63259547

Seth : 27956431

Cathy: 75821456

Given you have a variable as StudentCode that contains the list above (I think const will do! Like:

```js
const StudentCode = {
  [Jack]: [32658495],
  [Rose]: [35621548],
  [Lita]: [63259547],
  [Seth]: [27956431],
  [Cathy]:[75821456],
};
```

)
So here are the questions:

1st: Ho can I define them in URL below:
https://www.mylist.com/student=?StudentCode
So the link for example for Jack will be:
https://www.mylist.com/student=?32658495
The URL is imaginary. Don't click on it please.

2nd: By the way the overall list is above 800 people and I'm planning to save an external .js file to be called within the current code. So tell me about that too. Thanks a million

Comment: This question is still fairly confusing, what is the actual structure of the names list? How is that being translated to the `StudentConstant`. Since this is typescript the output from that constant would be something like `{  27956431: [27956431],  32658495: [32658495],... }` which seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
const StudentCode = {
  "Jack": "32658495",
  "Rose": "35621548",
  "Lita": "63259547",
  "Seth": "27956431",
  "Cathy": "75821456",
};
```

You can construct urls like:

```
const urls = Object.values(StudentCode).map((c) => `https://www.mylist.com?student=${c}`)
// urls: ['https://www.mylist.com?student=32658495', 'https://www.mylist.com?student=35621548', 'https://www.mylist.com?student=63259547', 'https://www.mylist.com?student=27956431', 'https://www.mylist.com?student=75821456']
```

To get the url for a specific student simply do:

```
const url = `https://www.mylist.com?student=${StudentCode["Jack"]}`
// url: 'https://www.mylist.com?student=32658495'
```

Not sure I understand your second question - 800 is a rather low number so will not be any performance issues with it if that is what you are asking?

Comment: Just to prevent making a long code. Would you please think about it, external JS file?

Comment: Depends on the setup, if the file is served alongside you javascript simply do something like: `const StudentCode = require('students.json')`

Comment: I recieve a variable from the server that states the student name. How can I use this code to match the name with ${StudentCode[XXXX]}? The variable is used as "l18" and I can use it. So is there a line like: if (l18=${StudentCode.***}) {
const url = `https://www.mylist.com?student=${StudentCode["***]}`
}
What you see is my own language whose a dummy. Sorry about that.
I wonder how to implement the l18 variable if it matches one of these students.
Simply we can say that if l18 is, let's say, Jack then the url should be received from const StudentCode as [Jack].
Thanks for your attention

Comment: Are you in control of the data you receive from the server or is it as you outline in your question? If you are able to control it, then it would be much preferred that the keys are unique id's - you cannot create a reliable system that relies on names.

Comment: As for l18 no but I have a playground to add JavaScript codes. And now I need to make all the links out from the given name that l18 sends cause the links have no variable. So for each student l18 is variable that represents their names.

Const is a block based command then we can define their names separately from the server and then define the link for each individual (which is not defined from server-side). So if l18 matches Jack and his code in StudentCode const is 32658495 then how can we create the link?
These problems come out of that server, hehe:).. Thanks for the answers you send.

Comment: Maybe you're tired of my questions. Sorry anyway

Comment: Not sure I understand your question fully, sorry. The playground you mention - can you share that so I can make a fork, maybe then I will be better able to help out.

Comment: I think I would be able to convey my request correctly here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71978704/using-variable-results-contents-to-create-new-variables

To stop taking peoples precious times.

Answer (score 0):

The properties of the object (after the trailing comma is removed) can be looped through using a `for-in` loop, (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

This gives references to each key of the array and the value held in that key can be referenced using `objectName[key]`, Thus you will loop through your object using something like:

```
     for (key in StudentCode) { 
       keyString = key; // e.g = "Jack"
       keyValue = StudentCode[key]; // e.g. = 32658495
       // build the urls and links
     }
```

to build the urls, string template literals will simplify the process (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) allowing you to substitute values in your string. e.g.:

```
  url = `https://www.mylist.com/student=?${StudentCode[key]`}
```

Note the use of back ticks and `${}` for the substitutions.

Lastly, to build active links, create an element and sets its `innerHTML` property to markup built using further string template literals:

```
  let link = `<a href=${url}>${keyValue}</a>`
```

These steps are combined in the working snippet here:

```js
const StudentCode = {
  Jack: 32658495,
  Rose: 35621548,
  Lita: 63259547,
  Seth: 27956431,
  Cathy: 75821456,
};

 const studentLinks = [];
 
 for (key in StudentCode) { 
  let url = `https://www.mylist.com/student=?${StudentCode[key]}`;
  console.log(url);
  studentLinks.push(`<a href href="url">${key}</a>`) 
 }
 
 
 let output= document.createElement('div');
 output.innerHTML = studentLinks.join("<br>");
 
 document.body.appendChild(output);
```