# using variable results (contents) to create new variables

Tags: javascript, url, constants, var

I need to allocate urls to students. And my website gives only JavaScript playground in which some variables are predefined within the server and I can only use them and their results and not to change them but I'm able to define new variables, functions etc..

What I'm looking for is to use the predefined variables' results and create new ones.

So the variable I'm talking about is "l18", the student name variable. I need to make every single student a url and I'm allowed to do this in that playground (define new).

I give every student a random number and the result is for example: Jack: 65214587, Peter: 84562321, Sally: 25412365, Richard: 96352148,etc..
The url begins with, for example, https://www.students.com/StudentCode= and after the "=" sign every student code should be added so for Peter we'll have https://www.students.com/StudentCode=84562321

Better clarify the question more: l18 gives you up names and you need to define variables that uses these names to allocate to their results (for example Peter) a number (84562321) to be used in url variable. Let's give it a result and suppose that l18 gives you Peter, then how will the code be?
Is it something like (sorry about the codes, they're not even beginner level):

```js
Const StudentCode = {
  Jack: 65214587,
  Peter: 84562321,
  Sally: 25412365,
  Richard: 96352148
}

if (l18 = $StudentCode[
    //*one of these student names in Const StudentCode*
  ]) {
  let url = "https://www.students.com/StudentCode=" + [
    //*the student code  (next to student name obtained from l18)
  ]
}
console.log(url)
```

Let me say that to clarify again that I don't aim to make any changes to l18, cause it's predefined.

Comment: _"they're not even beginner level"_ - Then get a tutorial and make them (at least) beginner level. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: That was a complement, buddy :)

Comment: Alright, Simply the question is: how can I use a variable occurrence to define a new variable? I think it's the easiest way to summarise my question.

Comment: Are you trying to check the student id matches the code? Use the below code to play around with.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const StudentCode = [
    {"id":"118","name":"Jack","code":"65214587"},
    {"id":"119","name":"Peter","code":"84562321"},
    {"id":"120","name":"Sally","code":"25412365"},
    {"id":"121","name":"Richard","code":"96352148"}
    ];

var checkcode = '65214587';   // How you get this code is up to you //
var match= StudentCode.filter(function(item) { return item.code=== checkcode });
var url_code = match[0].id;
var url_name = match[0].name;
var url = "https://www.students.com/StudentCode=" + url_code;

console.log("ID from CODE "+checkcode);
console.log("Link for "+url_name); 
console.log(url);

var checkid = '118';   // How you get this code is up to you //
var match2= StudentCode.filter(function(item) { return item.id=== checkid });
var url_code = match2[0].code;
var url_name = match2[0].name;
var url = "https://www.students.com/StudentCode=" + url_code;

console.log("CODE from ID "+checkid);
console.log("Link for "+url_name); 
console.log(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

You have not explained it that clearly because no where in your data is any reference to 118? But if I understand correctly, you want to create an array with the students id, name and code. Then when you have the student code you want to get the student id to put in a link or vice versa?

If that is correct, then this will work.

```
    const StudentCode = [
    {"id":"118","name":"Jack","code":"65214587"},
    {"id":"119","name":"Peter","code":"84562321"},
    {"id":"120","name":"Sally","code":"25412365"},
    {"id":"121","name":"Richard","code":"96352148"}
    ];

var checkcode = '65214587';   // How you get this code is up to you //
var match= StudentCode.filter(function(item) { return item.code=== checkcode });
var url_code = match[0].id;
var url_name = match[0].name;
var url = "https://www.students.com/StudentCode=" + url_code;

console.log("ID from CODE "+checkcode);
console.log("Link for "+url_name); 
console.log(url);

var checkid = '118';   // How you get this code is up to you //
var match2= StudentCode.filter(function(item) { return item.id=== checkid });
var url_code = match2[0].code;
var url_name = match2[0].name;
var url = "https://www.students.com/StudentCode=" + url_code;

console.log("CODE from ID "+checkid);
console.log("Link for "+url_name); 
console.log(url);
```

This code simply creates an array with your data, get the code you want and searches for it in the array and returns the id you need and the other way round too. Note, there is no error checking for if the code does not exist in it!

This should point you in the right direction hopefully

Comment: _"You have not explained it that clearly..."_ - Then how are you able two write an answer (and not just a guess)?

Comment: Because the ID 118 does not exist anywhere in his original data but makes a reference to it and yes I am assuming that is all!!!

Comment: Dear @JulesUK You're making sense! One more thing to go and we're there: is there a way to remove the item ```"id"```? The id for all of them is ```l18``` (when called, it gives up one of items of ```"name"```) and if ```l18``` matches one of the name items then the url will be, as you made, ```"https://www.students.com/StudentCode=" + url_code;```

Comment: _Then when you have the student code you want to get the student id to put in a link or vice versa?_ It's actually I wanna get the student code to put in a link. We have to listen to l18 that gives up one of the names so we use the name to match their code and then add the codes to the (incomplete part of the) link to produce the final url.

Comment: What do you mean listen to I18? You say when its called it gives up one of the items? So just a random one from the array or in order? Really confused mate